# Removing leading zero in pipe delimiter file using awk

Tags: awk

I have source file in pipe delimiter and needs to remove leading zeros

Initial file:

```
010N00000001|20100111|20150112|PA|3|00001|41|+0000000100.00|+0000000000.00|+0000000000.00|022|R| |
010N00000001|20100115|20150115|PA|3|00001|41|-0000000050.00|+0000000000.00|+0000000000.00|022|R| |
```

Required output:

```
010N00000001|20100111|20150112|PA|3|1|41|100.00|0|0|022|R||
010N00000001|20100115|20150115|PA|3|1|41|-50.00|0|0|022|R||
```

anybody provide `awk` syntax for above? I have more attributes, just would like to get an idea 6th and 8th source attributes to corresponding 6th and 8th of output attribute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"}{$6=sprintf("%1.0f",$6);$8=sprintf("%3.2f",$8);$9=sprintf("%1.0f",$9);$10=sprintf("%1.0f",$10)}1;' tt.txt

010N00000001|20100111|20150112|PA|3|1|41|100.00|0|0|022|R| |
010N00000001|20100115|20150115|PA|3|1|41|-50.00|0|0|022|R| |
```

- `%X`, where X is required digits.
- `.xf`, where x is required decimals.

[source](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-round-values-in-a-column-in-a-file-4175512588/)

Comment: Thank you msp9011:  $1 at the end says to print the unchanged attributes as it is ?

Answer (score 3):

For instance, if `file` contains your data:

```
awk -F\| -v OFS=\| '{ $6  = sprintf( "%.0f",  $6  )
                      $8  = sprintf( "%.2f",  $8  )
                      $9  = sprintf( "%.0f",  $9  )
                      $10 = sprintf( "%.0f",  $10 )
                      print }' file
```

The `-F\|` option sets the (input) field separator to the pipe symbol; `-v OFS=\|` does the same for the output field separator. The lines with the assignments simply reformat the respective fields using the `sprintf()`-function (which returns what the `printf()` would have printed with the same arguments), and at the end, the complete reformatted record is output using `print`.

As to the reformatting with `sprintf()`, you can pick from a host of [control letters](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Control-Letters.html#Control-Letters) and associated [modifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html#Format-Modifiers). The links are to the GNU awk documentation, but most characters are pretty universal.

Comment: Thank you,  Ozzy, your explanation is awesome, I was struck in a mind set that, 1st to 5th attributes are not changing, but you script has started from 6th and 8th ...where did you mentioned that 1st to 5th print as it is ?

Comment: @Mouli This is one of the beauties of `awk`: an entire record (here: a line) is referred to as `$0`; it is composed of the different fields into which it is automatically split based on the input field separator: `$1`, `$2`, etc. By assigning to `$6`, we update both `$6` and `$0`, and `$0` is what is eventually output by the `print` statement (`print` without arguments means `print $0`). So everything that is not explicitly updated simply remains the same.

Comment: @Mouli No problem. If the answer worked for you, you can mark it accordingly (i.e. "accept" it). Here at U&L SE, this is how we say "thank you". See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: last question, last attribute has spaces, can I trim those spaces ?

Comment: @Mouli Most certainly: try it with the `%.0s` format specifier on field `$13`.

Answer (score 0):

`numfmt` from the GNU Coreutils package is on its way to being useful for tasks like this - unfortunately it doesn't yet appear to accept multiple `--field`,`--format` specifications and apparently doesn't handle numbers with a unary `+`. With a bit of wrangling:

```
$ sed 's/[+ ]//g' file | 
    numfmt -d'|' --field=8 --format='%.2f' | numfmt -d'|' --field=6,9,10 --format='%.0f'
010N00000001|20100111|20150112|PA|3|1|41|100.00|0|0|022|R||
010N00000001|20100115|20150115|PA|3|1|41|-50.00|0|0|022|R||
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below command  and it worked fine as per expected output

```
k=`awk '{print NF}' example.txt | sort -nr| sed -n '1p'`

for ((j=1;j<=2;j++)); do for((i=1;i<=$k;i++)); do awk -F "| -v i="$i" -v j="$j"  'NR==j{print $i}' example.txt| sed "s/^[+-]//g"| sed "s/^0\{2,\}//g"| sed "s/^\..*/0/g"; done| tr "\n" "|"| sed 's/|$//g'| sed 's/^|//g'; done| sed -r "s/\s+/|\n/g"| sed "s/^|//g"
```

output

```
010N00000001|20100111|20150112|PA|3|1|41|100.00|0|0|022|R||
010N00000001|20100115|20150115|PA|3|1|41|50.00|0|0|022|R||
```

Comment: I notice that a `-50` in the input turned into a positive `50` in the output. Presumably `sed "s/^[+-]//g"` is doing that.  Also, your `awk -F "| -v i="$i" ...` doesn't appear to close the quotes around the `|`.